# neo4j.conf custom location

Tags: neo4j, configuration, command-line-interface

When starting a neo4j server (version: 5.1.0) from the CLI, how to specify a `neo4j.conf` file, instead of having neo4j looking for configuration files in the default locations? ([Default file locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#table-file-locations)).

`neo4j start [relative_path]/neo4j.conf` resulted in: `Unmatched argument at index 1: '../../../config/neo4j.conf'`, while the expectation is that the specific neo4j.conf file is used.

Comment: You can override the default config, in the default location itself.

Comment: yes, indeed. but the question is really to start the server specifying a custom location for neo4j.conf: for multiple environments reason, all the configuration files of our project dependencies (database, deno.land, ssl, etc.) are located in a specific directory, and the CI/CD picks the correct conf depending on the target environment.

Comment: I am afraid we can't specify the config file while starting the server.

Comment: according to Christophe Willemsen's accepted answer, and to neo4j CLI help, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--help` for the command to understand the arguments.

```
$ ./bin/neo4j --help
Usage: neo4j [-hV] [--expand-commands] [--verbose] [COMMAND]
A partial alias for 'neo4j-admin server'. Commands for working with DBMS process from 'neo4j-admin server' category can
be invoked using this command.
      --expand-commands   Allow command expansion in config value evaluation.
  -h, --help              Show this help message and exit.
  -V, --version           Print version information and exit.
      --verbose           Prints additional information.
Commands:
  version  Print version information and exit.
  help     Displays help information about the specified command
  console  Start server in console.
  restart  Restart the server daemon.
  start    Start server as a daemon.
  status   Get the status of the server.
  stop     Stop the server daemon.

Environment variables:
  NEO4J_CONF    Path to directory which contains neo4j.conf.
  NEO4J_DEBUG   Set to anything to enable debug output.
  NEO4J_HOME    Neo4j home directory.
  HEAP_SIZE     Set JVM maximum heap size during command execution. Takes a number and a unit, for example 512m.
  JAVA_OPTS     Used to pass custom setting to Java Virtual Machine executing the command. Refer to JVM documentation
about the exact format. This variable is incompatible with HEAP_SIZE and takes precedence over HEAP_SIZE.
```

So for providing a specific location for the `neo4j.conf` file you need to pass it as environment variable.

```
export NEO4J_CONF=/path/to/neo4j.conf && ./bin/neo4j start
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe (merci!) Using this env variable seems to work (when neo4j starts, the "Directoris in use:" shows the correct config file), but it looks like the config file is ignored anyway (at least, the server.directories.data entry is not taken in account), while it is taken in account when updating the neo4j.conf file located in NEO4J_HOME/conf

Comment: Sorry, I cannot comment on that, might be a bug in Neo4j 5, feel free to open an issue on the github repository ?

Answer (score 0):

when you start database you can see right side 3 dots. inside that click on open folder > Configuration.

thanks

Comment: Thanks Rathod, but this does not answer the question: the question is related to the CLI version of neo4j, when starting the server (`neo4j start`)